# Visual studion ( asp.net ) applications wont work on Windows 10 pro

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, visual-studio, windows-10

I have upgraded my system to Windows 10 Pro and installed visual studio community 2015, and I tried to work on some of my existing ASP.net MVC projects.
The issue that I am facing now is when I try to debug, ( run ) the application during development, It opens the browser as usual. but it does not show the web application in the browser.

I tried making a new project just incase something is wrong with my dev environment but the same issue exist.
I installed Visual studio 2013 Premium, update 5 and I tried my app. the same issue exists. I tried a new asp.net app but the problem still there.

my application is fine, because I was working on it using VS 2013 premium and windows 8.1 pro.

I am running the both version of visual studio as Admin.

I am not sure if I should change any permission on the system.

Comment: which browser will it open? Edge? Set the default browser to IE11 and look what happens.

Comment: I tried ie, Chrome, edge and I have the same issue regardless of browser. @magicandre1981